# How prevent a style sheet from loading in IE including versions 10 and 11

Tags: internet-explorer, stylesheet, css-animations, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I would like to create separate style-sheets, one for all IE versions and another one for "normal browsers" ;)

Comment: I believe you cant do it with html/css, you would have to check the useragent with javascript

Comment: Also you could post your code, and maybe we find out why is so glithcy in IE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> overwrite cssText if IE.  ewww nasty.  </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type=text/css>
        body { font-family:'Segoe UI',sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:black }
        #customLook { display:inline-block; margin-top:50px; margin-left:50px }
    </style>
    <link id=animstyle rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=animstyle.css>
    <script>
        var s= (animstyle.sheet||animstyle.styleSheet)                  // w3c-browser OR ie8
        if (s && s.cssText) s.cssText= ".customSpan:before{content:'not ';color:red}"   // only IE implements sheet.cssText  (including Edge)  it's r/w.
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=customLook>
        <span class=customSpan>ANIMATED</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this [online demo](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfmlRRjIyY2JOalNFMnNLLTBLaFh5ZFZPdnlDUDB0VmNOd19RTjIwY1lVNVE/unlink-CSS.html)
Actually, you could put `s.disabled=true` instead, and then enable some other css link.  That'd be more proper.  But I just had to post this, because it's so nasty.
**Edit**  Here's an easy way to disable one sheet and replace it with another:

```
        <link id=animstyle rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=animstyle.css>
        <script>
            var s= (animstyle.sheet||animstyle.styleSheet)                  // w3c-browser OR ie8
            if (s && s.cssText) s.disabled= true                        // only IE implements sheet.cssText  (including Edge)  it's r/w.
        </script>
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=NOanimstyle.css onload="(this.sheet||this.styleSheet).disabled=!s.disabled">
```

[demo ver2](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfmlRRjIyY2JOalNFMnNLLTBLaFh5ZFZPdnlDUDB0VmNOd19RTjIwY1lVNVE/unlink-CSS-ver2.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. Your demo certainly works. At least in IE11. Would this work for all IE versions? If that's the case I'd like to use this. I'm just not sure how it works. Sorry for being a complete illiterate regarding JavaScript. Are you suggesting I use one style-sheet that includes the animations and another one that doesn't? That could work for me... Where exactly would I place the second style-sheet link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser sniffing - something like [How can I target only Internet Explorer 11 with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447373/how-can-i-target-only-internet-explorer-11-with-javascript) and then load the right stylesheet using document.write (see [When using document.write to load a different css stylesheet, browser refreshes infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005272/when-using-document-write-to-load-a-different-css-stylesheet-browser-refreshes))

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answers your looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022279/ie-only-style-sheets-how-to-prevent-ie-from-loading-other-style-sheets)

Appears to have been answered already

Comment: If you were to use `<!--[if gt IE 9]>` it would be a condition on 10 or 11 for example.

Comment: I think Conditional Comments are no longer supported by versions 10 and 11. I've tested this and it didn't load the stylesheet: `<!--[if gt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

You can allways to something like this

```
<script>
var ltie11 = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var ie11 = /Trident/.test(navigator.userAgent);
if( ! (ltie11 || ie11) ) {
    var $link = $('<link>').attr('type','text/css').attr('src', 'css/css.css');
    $('body').append($link);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't load the style-sheet. Am I missing something? `<script>
var ltie11 = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
var ie11 = /Trident/.test(navigator.userAgent);
if( ! (ltie11 || ie11) ) {
    var $link = $('<link>').attr('type','text/css').attr('src', 'css/styles-no-animation.css');
    $('body')append.($link);
}
</script>`

Comment: Do you have jquery included and it's the correct path?

Comment: I'm using `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: There was a syntax error, please use the code from my update!

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console logs or have a link with the actuall code?