# Fixed padding in callout box of timeline chart

Tags: highcharts

We are creating callouts for timeline chart and padding getting different for callout boxes please refer attached spac [![calloutpaddingspac][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ixYQ.png

how we can set equal padding here in callouts?

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor that I could work on? I cannot see those differences in the official demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/timeline

Comment: Please use this for padding issue https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-timeline/connector-styles

Comment: I changed the default padding in datalabel, does it fix your issue? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ovcyq02w/

Comment: No Here we can see in callout upper and lower gap is not equal

Comment: I cannot see any difference - tested on the newest version of the chrome & macOS Catalina.

Comment: I have posted a answer Please look into this we are getting same issue in padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: ImageWithPaddingissue]

Kindly check the highlighted part of above image, that i got using below link
'https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-timeline/connector-styles'

Comment: I cannot see those gaps - https://imgur.com/a/zgHtLVN

Comment: We are using Win 10 Chrome it is not working there  but when we checked in MAC it is working for us, any thing that we need to do ?

Comment: This issue is not related to using the Highcharts library, but with the general differences between those operating systems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074784/slight-differences-between-mac-and-windows-css-rendering-font-letter-spacing

Comment: Can we  do anything at our end , so we can do make it similar on both OS?

Comment: From Highcharts side - not.