# Can I add in css or js a InternetExplorer version of website

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer

thanks you guys for visit this question.
I was wondering if there is any way to make an internet explorer version of a website.
Like I use in css the tag @media to "responsive" and change things.

Because like you know no ones use internetexplorer. only companies
And I need a version of my website compatibility to iE.
The only thing its wrong in my web is the "js" slider image or jquery but the "html5" code is correct and works fine in internet explorer.
How can I fix that?

Thanks, regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019725/create-css-for-internet-explorer-only

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im going to use in the css style file, a "display.none" to the "js slider" :D ty